# Using the definition of a vector space to prove that $0x = 0$ and $(-1)x = -x$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

Let $x$ be an element of a vector space. I am trying to use the definition of a vector space to prove that $0x = 0$ and $(-1)x = -x$.

Let $w + x = x$  for all $x \in E$.

$$\begin{align} 0x &= 0(w + x) \\ &= 0w + 0x \\ &= 0w + 0(-w) \\ &= 0w - 0w \\ &= 0 \end{align}$$

Now, I think this is correct for proving that $0x = 0$, but I don't think it actually proves that $(-1)x = -x$, but rather just assumes it to be true. Am I correct in my assessment of this? If so, I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to explain how we are supposed to prove both of these at the same time.

### EDIT

The definition of vector space is given as follows:

> By a vector space we mean a nonempty set $E$ with two operations:
>
> $(x, y) \mapsto x + y$ from $E \times E$ into $E$ called *addition*.
>
> $(\lambda, x) \mapsto \lambda x$ from $\mathbb{F} \times E$ into $E$ *multiplication* by scalars,
>
> such that the following conditions are satisfied for all $x, y, z \in E$ and $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{F}$:
>
> (a) $x + y = y + x$;
>
> (b) $(x + y) + z = x + (y + z)$
>
> (c) For every $x, y \in E$ there exists a $z \in E$ such that $x + z = y$;
>
> (d) $\alpha (\beta x) = (\alpha \beta) x$;
>
> (e) $(\alpha + \beta)x = \alpha x + \beta x$;
>
> (f) $\alpha(x + y) = \alpha x + \alpha y$
>
> (g) $1x = x$
>
> Elements of $E$ are called vectors. If $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}$, then $E$ is called a real vector space, and if $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{C}$, $E$ is called a complex vector space.

From chapter 1 of *Introduction to Hilbert Spaces with Applications*, third edition, by Debnath and Mikusinski.

I found [this](https://docs.ufpr.br/%7Ejrrb/DebnathMikusinski.pdf) (see 3.(c) on page 5) solution:

> Since $0x = (0 + 0)x = 0x + 0x$, it follows that $0x = 0$. Then
>
> $$\begin{align} x + (-1)x &= 1x + (-1)x \\ &= [1 + (-1)]x \\ &= 0x \\ &= 0 \end{align}$$
>
> Therefore $(-1)x = 0 - x = -x$.

How is the first line of this solution valid reasoning?

> Since $0x = (0 + 0)x = 0x + 0x$, it follows that $0x = 0$.

In order to deduce from $0x = 0x + 0x$ that $0x = 0$, doesn't one already have to assume that $0x = 0$?

Comment: The second one can be proven by using $(-1)x+x=x(-1+1)=x\cdot 0=0$, but isn't $0x=0$ for all $x$ contained in the usual definition of a vector space ?

Comment: How did you replace $x$ with $-w$? Typically one proves this by considering the fact that$$0x=(0+0)x=0x+0x$$

Comment: @PeterForeman Yes, this is the standard proof I forgot for a moment. We just have to use "$0+0=0$"

Comment: @Peter Definition 1.2.1. of *Introduction to Hilbert Spaces with Applications*, third edition, by Debnath and Mikusinski, does not list $0x = 0$. The closest it lists is $1x = x$.

Comment: @PeterForeman Do you share my doubts of the correctness of the shown proof for "$0x=0$" ?

Comment: @PeterForeman We have that $x, w \in E$, and although $w + x = x$ necessitates $w$ be equal to some specific value (that being $0$), we have the freedom to choose any $x \in E$, so we use this freedom to select $x = -w$. At least, that is the reasoning I used.

Comment: @ThePointer But you have to show this is true for every $x$ in the vector space. You have only shown it is true for $x=-w$.

Comment: @PeterForeman In the textbook, the author showed that "there exists exactly one element $z \in E$ such that $x + z = x$ for all $x \in E$. That element is denoted by $0$ and called the zero vector." I assumed this is true, and then I tried to use this to do what I just described. Is this reasoning flawed?

Comment: Since $w=0$ must hold , $x=-w$ is only correct for $x=0$ , so you cannot replace $x$ by $-w$

Comment: @Peter Yes, you're right.

Comment: Does anyone have any comments on the edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the axioms as you give them don't even explicitly state that a zero vector exists, and therefore that fact first has to be proven.

What axiom (c) guarantees is that for every vector $x$ there exists a vector $0_x$ such that $x + 0_x = x$. Note that at this point we don't know yet that $0_x$ is unique, nor that $0_x = 0_y$ for $x\ne y$.

Let us first prove uniqueness of $0_x$ for given $x$. For this, let us first note that axiom (c) also guarantees us a vector $n_x$ so that $x+n_x=0_x$.

Now let's assume there is a second vector $0'_x$ such that $x+0'_x=x$. Again, axiom (c) guarantees us an element $n'_x$ such that $x+n'_x = 0'_x$.

Thus we have
$$0_x = x + n_x = (0'_x + x) + n_x = 0'_x + (x+n_x) = 0'_x + 0_x = (n'_x + x) + 0_x = n'_x + (x + 0_x) = n'_x + x = 0'_x$$
That is, the element $0_x$ is indeed unique for each $x$. We also can easily verify that $0x = 0_x$:

We have $x = 1x = (1+0)x = 1x + 0x = x+0x$. But we have seen above that the solution $x+y=x$ has the unique solution $0_x$, therefore $0x=0_x$ (and I'll use that notation exclusively from now on).

What remains to be shown is that $0x = 0y$ for $x\ne y$.

Be $z$ the vector such that $0x+z=0y$; this vector is guaranteed to exist by axiom (c). Adding $0x+0y$ to both sides gives us $0x+0y+z=0x+0y$, therefore $z=0(0x+0y) = 0x+0y$. Inserting into the original equation gives us $0x+0x+0y=0y$, that is, $0x+0y=0y$. By exchanging the roles of $0x$ and $0y$ we also get $0x+0y=0x$, and therefore $0x=0y$. Since $x$ and $y$ were arbitrary, we have now established that all products of the form $0x$ result in the same vector, which by convention we call $0$.

Now that we have showed the existence and uniqueness of $0$, we can also show the uniqueness of $n_x$ for given $x$: Let's assume there are $n_x$ and $n'_x$ such that $x+n_x = x+n'_x = 0$. Then we have $n_x = n_x + 0 = n_x + x + n'_x = 0 + n'_x = n'_x$.

Having shown the uniqueness of $n_x$, we can now also give it the more conventional name $-x$.

With this in place, it is now easy to show that $(-1)x=-x$, using the definition that $-x$ is the element that fulfils $x+(-x)=0$:
$$x+(-1)x = 1x+(-1)x = (1+(-1))x = 0x = 0$$
The uniqueness of $-x$ then guarantees that $(-1)x=-x$.

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding this part: $n_x = x_x + 0 = n_x + x + n'_x = 0 + n'_x = n'_x$. Where did the $x_x$ come from, and what purpose does it serve?

Comment: @ThePointer: The $x_x$ should have been an $n_x$, fixed now. Sorry for all the typos.

Comment: Ahh, ok. It's all fine. I'm just happy for the comprehensive answer.

Comment: I took the time to carefully study your answer. I'm surprised that the proof is this difficult. Since the authors posed this as an early problem, I suspect that they thought that it would be easier. Perhaps they misjudged how difficult it would be, given their provided definition of vector spaces. What do you think of the proof in my edit? Is it valid?

Comment: @ThePointer: It may well be that earlier in that book there were some statements proved that could be used to simplify this (e.g. they might have defined fields in a similar way, and already proved some of the things I explicitly proved here). The prove in your edit definitely makes use of things that I proved explicitly above (note that most of my post is concerned with proving the existence of the vector $0$, which that proof just assumes to exist). Note also that I cannot guarantee that I've found the simplest way to prove it.

Answer (score 2):

I'll use the vector space axioms given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space). Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $K$ and let $a \in K$, $\mathbf{v} \in V$. By the definition of $0$, $$0\mathbf{v}=(a+(-a))\mathbf{v}=a\mathbf{v} - a\mathbf{v}=a(\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{v})=a\mathbf{0}=\mathbf{0}.$$
All these statements follow directly from the axioms given on Wikipedia.

Comment: You can use $a=0$ if you want to avoid that last step, if you wish.

Comment: With $a=0$ , it is the proof mentioned above

Comment: Where does this prove that $(-1)x = -x$?