# Prove $(\forall x, y \in E)(\exists ! z\in Z)$ s. t. $x + z = y$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

I am currently studying *Introduction to Hilbert Spaces with Applications*, the third edition, by Debnath and Mikusinski. Chapter 1, exercise 1, is as follows:

> 1. Prove that for every $x, y \in E$ there exists a unique $z \in E$ such that $x + z = y$.

The definition of vector space is given as follows:

> By a vector space we mean a nonempty set $E$ with two operations:
>
> $(x, y) \mapsto x + y$ from $E \times E$ into $E$ called *addition*.
>
> $(\lambda, x) \mapsto \lambda x$ from $\mathbb{F} \times E$ into $E$ *multiplication* by scalars,
>
> such that the following conditions are satisfied for all $x, y, z \in E$ and $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{F}$:
>
> (a) $x + y = y + x$;
>
> (b) $(x + y) + z = x + (y + z)$
>
> (c) For every $x, y \in E$ there exists a $z \in E$ such that $x + z = y$;
>
> (d) $\alpha (\beta x) = (\alpha \beta) x$;
>
> (e) $(\alpha + \beta)x = \alpha x + \beta x$;
>
> (f) $\alpha(x + y) = \alpha x + \alpha y$
>
> (g) $1x = x$
>
> Elements of $E$ are called vectors. If $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}$, then $E$ is called a real vector space, and if $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{C}$, $E$ is called a complex vector space.

Chapter 1 already contains a proof that it seems would prove this (modified by me):

---

Let $x, y \in E$. By (c), there exists a $w \in E$ such that $x + w = y$. If $x + z_x = x$ for some $z_x \in E$, then, by (a) and (b),

$$y + z_x = (x + w) + z_x = (x + z_x) + w = x + w = y.$$

This proves that $z$ exists for every $x, y \in E$.

Now let $z_1, z_2 \in E$ such that $x + z_1 = x$ and $y + z_2 = y$ for all $x, y \in E$.

Therefore, we have that

$$z_1 + z_2 = z_1$$

and

$$z_2 + z_1 = z_2$$

Therefore, we can conclude that $z_1 = z_2$.

---

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to review this proof for correctness.

Comment: Doesn't (c) already give existence and you just need to prove uniqueness?

Comment: @SahibaArora Yes, that's what I thought. But it seems to me that this proof does both, no?

Comment: The proof you quote seems to show uniqueness of the additive identity - i.e., an element $z$ such that for all $x \in E$, $x+z=x$. You want to prove uniqueness of $w$ from (c). However, the proof will be similar. (c) tells you that there exists $z$ such that $x+z=y$. Then suppose there is also $z'$ such that $x+z'=y$, and show $z=z'$.

Comment: @kccu I've been unable to see how such a thing can be proven. I must be missing some fact about the axioms (in particular, (c)).

Comment: @ThePointer Does Sahbia's answer below show you how this can be proven?

Comment: @kccu I do not think that it is a valid proof. The part with $x + x^\prime = 0$ constructs the additive inverse. But what we actually need is to construct is $0$ -- not the additive inverse. $x^\prime + (x + z_1) = x^\prime + (x + z_2)$ is then constructed, and it is said that, using (b), we can get from here to $z_1 = z_2$. Constructing the additive inverse in the part with $x + x^\prime = 0$, and combining this with the construction of  $x^\prime + (x + z_1) = x^\prime + (x + z_2)$ and (b), does allow us to derive that $z_1 = z_2$. [...]

Comment: [...] You are *still* left with $x + z_1 = x + z_2$; how do you get from here to $z_1 = z_2$? That was the problem before constructing the additive inverse using $x + x^\prime = 0$, but the construction of the additive inverse using $x + x^\prime = 0$ does not get us any closer to this goal. It seems to me that there is a logical discontinuity somewhere in this part.

Comment: You are correct that you need to existence of $0$ and its property that $x+0=x$ for all $x \in E$ before you can proceed with the proof. However, once you have that the proof goes through. I don't see why you claim that $x'+(x+z_1)=x'+(x+z_2)$ and $x+x'=0$ does not allow you to conclude $z_1=z_2$.

Comment: @kccu The existence and uniqueness of the additive identity was proved in the answer I linked. That question was I asked by OP too, so I took the luxury to assume that OP already has that information.

Comment: Hmm, I just started thinking about this answer differently, and I think I understand where my issue was. I was taking $x + z_1 = x + z_2$ first, then considering $x + x^\prime = 0$, and then considering $x^\prime + (x + z_1) = x^\prime + (x + z_2)$. This left me wondering how one uses $x + z_1 = x + z_2$ and $x + x^\prime = 0$ together to then get $x^\prime + (x + z_1) = x^\prime + (x + z_2)$. [...]

Comment: @ThePointer I think you've got it now. $x+x'=0$ is not needed to go from $x+z_1=x+z_2$ to $x'+(x+z_1)=x'+(x+z_2)$. The latter equation follows from $x+z_1=x+z_2$ alone simply by adding the same thing to both sides (namely, $x'$, but we could just as well add any other element of $E$). The reason for adding $x'$, though, is because then we can use the property $x+x'=0$ to "clean up" the equation, replacing each $x'+x$ by $0$.

Comment: [...] But if we begin by considering $x + z_1 = x + z_2$, and then consider $x^\prime + (x + z_1) = x^\prime + (x + z_2)$, and *then* consider how one relates $x + x^\prime = 0$ with $x^\prime + (x + z_1) = x^\prime + (x + z_2)$ *after* using (b), it now becomes clear! We have $x^\prime + (x + z_1) = x^\prime + (x + z_2)$ by construction. Using (b), we have that $(x^\prime + x) + z_1 = (x^\prime + x) + z_2$, and considering that $x + x^\prime = 0$, we have that $0 + z_1 = 0 + z_2 \Rightarrow z_1 = z_2$. @SahibaArora Does this look correct to you?

Comment: @kccu Yes! I was thinking about the proof in the same way that I was reading it: sequentially. So I just wasn't thinking of things in a way that would make sense (how do you get from $x + z_1 = x + z_2$ to $x^\prime + (x + z_1) = x^\prime + (x + z_2)$ using the constructed fact that $x + x^\prime = 0$?). Now it makes complete sense. I'm shocked that I confused it so badly by just by thinking about it in a slightly different way. Thank you both for taking the time to clarify this for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existence is guaranteed by (c). You just need to prove uniqueness. Suppose there exists $z_1,z_2 \in E$ such that $$x+z_1=y, x+z_2=y.$$ Then $$x+z_1=x+z_2.\tag{1}$$ By (c), corresponding to $x \in E$ and $0 \in E$ (whose existence and uniqueness are proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3705574/266110)), there exists $x' \in E$ such that $x+x'=0.$
Therefore by $(1),$ $$x'+(x+z_1)=x'+(x+z_2)$$ and finally (b) implies $z_1=z_2.$

Your solution actually shows the uniqueness of additive identity.

Comment: "By (c), there exists $x' \in E$ such that $x+x'=0.$" I'm not sure that this is a valid assumption. I think what (c) shows is that, for every $x \in E$, there exists a $z_x \in E$ such that $x + z_x = x$, but I don't think that this is the same as showing that $x + x' = 0$.

Comment: I think you're reading (c) wrong. It says for every $x,y \in E,$ there exists $z \in E$ such that $x+z=y.$ In particular, take $y=0.$

Comment: Ahh, ok, I see. And how did you get $x'+(x+z_1)=x'+(x+z_2)$?

Comment: @ThePointer Using $x+z_1=x+z_2$ by direct substitution.

Comment: So you set $y = x$ for $x+z_1=y, x+z_2=y$?

Comment: @ThePointer I don't think I get your question. If $a=b$ and $b=c,$ then $a=c$ because $=$ is a transitive relation. We have $x+z_1=y$ and $x+z_2=y,$ so $x+z_1=x+z_2.$ This gives $x'+(x+z_1)=x'+(x+z_2).$ It follows that $0+z_1=0+z_2$ and by the answer I linked away, we obtain $z_1=z_2.$

Comment: You claim that $x+x'=0$, and then you claim that, therefore, $x'+(x+z_1)=x'+(x+z_2)$. You said that you did this by using $x+z_1=x+z_2$ by direct substitution. So is this because $x + z_1$ and $x + z_2$ are elements of $E$? The reasoning here is not clear to me.

Comment: @ThePointer Let $w =x+z_1 \in E.$ Then as shown $w=x+z_2.$ Therefore $x'+(x+z_1)=x'+w=z'+(x+z_2).$ The only thing I'm using here is that $=$ is an equivalence relation.

Comment: It seems to me that there is a discontinuity in reasoning here. You went from $x' \in E$ and $x+x'=0$ to $x'+(x+z_1)=x'+(x+z_2)$, but it is not clear that $x'+(x+z_1)=x'+(x+z_2)$ is implied by what preceded it. I know that $=$ is an equivalence relation, but I don't see how this is relevant to the point I'm making. At the moment, you're claiming that $x' \in E$ and $x+x'=0$ implies that $x'+(x+z_1)=x'+(x+z_2)$, but I'm confused as to how this is the true.

Comment: No, I did not go from $x+x'=0$ to $x'+(x+z_1)=x'+(x+z_2).$ I went from $x+z_1=x+z_2$ to $x'+(x+z_1)=x'+(x+z_2)$ because the elements in the brackets in LHS and RHS are the **same** element.

Comment: Oh, but that was what I asked before: We have $x + x' = 0$, so if we let $y = x$, then we get $y + x' = 0$, and so $(x + z_1) + x' = 0$ and $(x + z_2) + x' = 0$, which implies that $(x + z_1) + x' = 0 = (x + z_2) + x'$, and so $(x + z_1) + x' = (x + z_2) + x'$. But perhaps you're using different reasoning to me here? But I am not sure if my reasoning here is valid, since setting $y = x$ might invalidate the proof, since we no longer have any $y, x \in E$?

Comment: You are already given $x, y \in E.$ You cannot let $y=x.$ Moreover, you are over-complicating the problem. Let me rephrase a bit. We have $x+z_1=y.$ So $x'+(x+z_1)=x'+y.$ But we also have $y=x+z_2$ (by choice of $z_2$), so $x'+y=x'+(x+z_2).$ Now do you see that $x'+(x+z_1)=x'+y=x'+(x+z_2)$?

Answer (score -1):

Let $z, z^\prime, w \in E$.

From (c), it follows that there exists a $w \in E$ such that $z + w = z^\prime$.

Let $x + z = y = x + z^\prime$ and $z + w = z^\prime$.

Then

$$y = x + z^\prime = x + z + w = y + w.$$

Therefore, we must have that $w = 0$.

And so, we have that

$$z^\prime = z + w = z.$$

Comment: This solution is full of problems. First you let $w \in E$ (so $w$ is arbitrary?). Then you say $w$ is chosen to satisfy $x+w=x$ (so $w$ possibly depends on $x$?). Then you say $w$ is chosen so that $z+w=z'$ (so $w$ possibly depends on $z$ and $z'$?). You cannot let $w \in E$ and then assert that it satisfies those other equations without justification.

Comment: @kccu That was a typo. Thanks. What about now?

Comment: In addition to @kccu's comments: Just look at your first and last line. You pick arbitrary $z,z'\in E$ and show $z=z'.$ That means $E=\{z\}$ but $E$ was an arbitrary vector space.

Comment: @SahibaArora Hmm, I think I might have described it incorrectly. What about now?

Comment: @ThePointer You still start with arbitrary $z,z',w.$ The first three lines should be written as follows: Let $x,y \in E$ and $z,z' \in E$ be such that $x+z=y$ and $x+z'=y.$ By (c), there exists $w \in E$ such that $z+w=z'.$